# Laravel Ajax request returning whole page rather than just data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use ajax to find the next page on my pagination. However it keeps bringing in the whole body. I've taken a print screen to show the problem.

I'm not an expert on ajax show would appreciate some help as to how I can rectify this issue?

My code is below:

```
public function viewall()
{
    $data["projects"] = $projects = Auth::user()->projects()->paginate(3);

    if(Request::ajax())
            {

            $html = View::make('projects.viewall', $data)->render();
            return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
        }

        return View::make('projects.viewall')->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

Js/js.js

```
$(".pagination a").click(function()
{
    var myurl = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: myurl,
        type: "get",
        datatype: "html",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $('#ajax-loading').show();
        }
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        $('#ajax-loading').hide();
        $("#projects").empty().html(data.html);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
          alert('No response from server');
    });
    return false;
});
```

viewall.blade.php

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")

<div class="container"> 
<h4>Your Projects</h4>

<div id="ajax-loading" class="alert alert-warning" style="display: none;">
<strong>Loading...</strong>
</div>

@if (Auth::check())
    @if (count($projects) > 0)
   @foreach ($projects as $project)

   <div class="one-third column" id="projects">

  {{ $project->project_name }}
    {{ $project->project_brief }}
   {{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime($project->start_day)) }}

   </div>

   @endforeach 
   @else
    <h5 class="errorslist">You have no projects click <a class="errorslist" href="/project/create">here to create a project</a></h5>
@endif
  @endif

  <div class="sixteen columns">
    {{ $projects->links() }}
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#projects").empty().html(data.html);
```

will fill the `#project` up with your returned `html` which you created here:

`$html = View::make('projects.viewall', $data)->render()`;

So,you just need to change `projects.viewall` with only 'partial view' that you want to load.

Probably you don't need to extends your main layout.

Comment: I see I put the retrieve script in another file and included this into the viewall file. I call this as so `$html = View::make('projects.viewprojects', $data)->render();` in this file I have pasted from the if statement to the end of the sixteen columns div. It works however if I go one page back it doesn't seem to be AJAX

Comment: the url changes to the url changes to project/viewall?page=1

Comment: no worries fixed it, had to put the js in a different file to my other js scripts

Answer (score 0):

But you render a view here:

```
$html = View::make('projects.viewall', $data)->render();
```

so html is created by Laravel and then you insert it as html into the #projects domElement.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this kind of problem, just run

```
dd( json_decode( json_encode( Products::paginate(5) ), true) );
```

and can get a hint :)

I have read a solution about this here:

http://www.tagipuru.xyz/2016/05/17/displaying-data-using-laravel-pagination-in-the-html-table-without-page-reload/